What's the right router bit for the edge of my table?
I have an antique wooden table that expands with leaves. The shape of the leaves matches the table, but the wood and shade are wrong, and the leaves are in poor condition, one with a tire track, one with a boot print, all with chips in the veneer. I would like to try to craft new leaves, but I can't find a router bit that matches my table. Does this design have a name? Is it common if I just know what to ask for?
The table seems to be 3/4 of an inch thick, and the pattern seems to be inset 11/16 or maybe 3/4 of an inch in from the edge. There is an undated label on the underside from The North American Furniture Co. Ltd of Owen Sound Canada.
Pictures below.





To match antique profiles, you may need to take multiple passes with different router bits, each cutting onlly a portion of the shape (indeed, they were frequently cut with multiple planes, rather than one with the full profile.) If it's not that antique, they probably ground a shaper cutter for the job at the factory.

Agreed.  You'll just need to do some shopping for table edge router bits with whatever dimensions that match your profile.  The bottom looks pretty close to a simple quarter round, but again you'll need to match the dimension.
